# Running bash scripts parallel in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I am trying to run a script (1.sh)

```
spin -a  /home/files/1/1.pml; 
gcc -O2 -DXUSAFE -DSAFETY -DNOCLAIM -w -o pan pan.c >log1.txt; 
./pan -m100000 >log2.txt; 
spin -p -s -r -X -v -n123 -l -g -k /home/files/1/1.pml.trail \
    -u10000 /home/files/1/1.pml >log3.txt;
```

The command `spin -a ...;` generates temporary files (pan.c, pan.h) which is used by the next `gcc -O2..` command. If I run the script in terminal it creates the temporary files in the same location.

I want to run multiple scripts parallelly. I tried two things, first to write a script to run then in a loop in background (parallel.sh)

```
for((i=1;i<1800;i++))
 do 
   /home/files/$i/$i.sh & 
 done
```

and secondly use parallel gnu `parallel -j0 sh /home/files/{}/{}.sh ::: {1..1800}`.

Both method created temp file in the location from where they were called from instead of the script location.

For example if I run the script 'parallel.sh' from `home/files` the temp file are created in "home/files" instead of the location "home/files/1","home/files/2", etc.

Please suggest a method so that the temporary file generated by the script 1.sh,2.sh,.. are created in the directory `/home/file/1/`, `/home/files/2/`,.. respectively while I run the parallel script parallel.sh or parallel GNU in terminal from location `/home`.

Comment: The simplest fix would be to add a `cd` command to your script so that each invocation goes to the directory you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to change the working directory for each command.

When your computer can really run up to 1800 such processes at the same time without heating up the climate:

```
for i in {1..1800}; do (cd $i && ./$i.sh) & done
```

When running in parallel, and your processes are cpu-bound, it usually does not gain throughput when running more than the number of processors:

```
seq 1 1800 | xargs -n1 -P8 -I% sh -c 'cd % && ./%.sh'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parallel 'cd /home/files/{}; sh {}.sh' ::: {1..1800}
```

It will run one process per core, and may be faster than '-j0' (only testing can tell with certainty).

If your scripts only vary by the number, consider rewriting it as a general script or bash function that takes the number as an argument:

```
spinit() {
    num=$1
    spin -a  /home/files/$num/$num.pml; 
    gcc -O2 -DXUSAFE -DSAFETY -DNOCLAIM -w -o pan pan.c >log1.txt; 
    ./pan -m100000 >log2.txt; 
    spin -p -s -r -X -v -n123 -l -g -k /home/files/$num/$num.pml.trail \
        -u10000 /home/files/$num/$num.pml >log3.txt;
}
export -f spinit
parallel 'cd /home/files/{}; spinit {}' ::: {1..1800}
```